# Labels are not displayed while using mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I am trying to have a simple tab view using angular material `mat-tab-group`.

`app.module.ts` and `app.component.html` file -

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Your financial portfolio</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<div>
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Labels are not visible.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You followed the docs. So in order to help I need you to create a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is true I think you changed color of `.mat-tab-label, .mat-tab-link` then test this in `.css` file:

```css
.mat-tab-label, .mat-tab-link {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello here I leave an example, this works for me.
The key is in **ng-template mat-tab-label** inside it you can add a **span** and color the text black.

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span style="color: black;">First</span>
    </ng-template>
    Content 1
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span style="color: black;">Second</span>
    </ng-template>
    Content 2
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span style="color: black;">Third</span>
    </ng-template>
    Content 3
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks.
Just a note - It's not a good practice to use styles in html, instead use them in a separate css file and use respective classes in html like the one also suggested in the accepted answer.